# Why emerging stock markets are where investors diversify and hedge against the country-specific uncertainty of their local stock markets?

Tags: stock-market, international-economics

[Civilize, 2015](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1566014115000023?via%3Dihub) states that

> Our study focuses on emerging stock markets of countries that have a
> history of military rule. An investigation of these markets is
> valuable for investors, particularly during such periods of military
> interference, since these markets are **important venues through which
> investors diversify and hedge against the country-specific uncertainty
> of their local stock markets**

In this paragraph, the author says that emerging markets are the places that investors diversify and hedge against the country-specific uncertainty of their local stock markets. I am wondering why it is the case?
I am asking this question because why investors do not invest in developed market to hedge but developing market, where are very uncertainty.

Comment: The author doesn't really seems to be saying that emerging markets are *the* places where investors diversify against country-specific uncertainties. He's just stating that they are important places where they do that. He doesn't make a call (at least in this piece of text) on *how* important they are.